# Convert three modelsto one single query django query

Tags: django-models

This are my model with some of the fields:

```
class Advertisers(models.Model):
    account_manager_id = models.ForeignKey(AccountManagers, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, db_column='account_manager_id',related_name="advertisers")

class AdvertiserUsers(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField('Users', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,db_column='user_id', related_name='advertiser_users')
    advertiser_id = models.ForeignKey('Advertisers', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,db_column='advertiser_id', related_name='advertiser_users')


class Users(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
```

I want Id's, user ids and email of all advertisers.

Id's of all user:-

```
advertiser_ids = advertisers.objects.all() # can get id from here
```

find user_ids of advertiser_ids:

```
user_ids = AdvertiserUsers.objects.filter(advertiser_id__in=advertiser_ids) # can get user_id from here
```

find id and email using this query:

```
user_ids = Users.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids) # can get email from here
```

How to make it shorter like directly querying from Advertisers i will be able to get Users models email.

Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Users.objects.filter(advertiser_users__advertiser_id__isnull=False).distinct()
```

The [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) will prevent returning the *same* `Users` multiple times.

You can annotate the `User` objects with the `Advertisers` primary key, etc:

```
from django.db.models import F

Users.objects.filter(advertiser_users__advertiser_id__isnull=False).annotate(
    account_manager_id=F('advertiser_users__advertiser_id__account_manager_id'),
    advertiser_id=F('advertiser_users__advertiser_id')
)
```

The `Users` objects that arise from this have a `.email` attribute (and the other attributes that belong to a `Users` object), together with a `.account_manager_id` and an `.advertiser_id`. That being said, this is probably *not* a good idea: the way you have modeled this right now, is that a `Users` object can relate to *multiple* `Advertisers` objects, so it makes not much sense to add these together.

You can for each user access the related `Advertiser`s with:

```
myusers = Users.objects.filter(
    advertiser_users__advertiser_id__isnull=False
).prefetch_related(
    'advertiser_users',
    'advertiser_users__advertiser_id'
).distinct()
for user in myusers:
    print(f'{user.email}')
    for advuser in user.advertiser_users.all():
        print(f'    {advuser.advertiser_user.pk}')
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `User` instead of <s>`Users`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `account_manager_id`, instead of <s>`account_manager`</s>.

Comment: I want id,user_id and email.

Answer (score 0):

```
Advertisers.objects.all().values_list('id','account_manager_id','advertiser_users__user_id',advertiser_users__user_id__email)
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: Please don't use `.values()`. This is a [*primitive obsession* antipattern](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession).